# Iframe not following redirects

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that contains a form that is automatically submitted when the page loads, the iframe is being rendered and it shows the form before submission, but the page that should render after the form post request it's not showing in the iframe. What could I do to solve this?

The code:

```
<iframe srcdoc="<html>
<body>
    <form name='sendFingerprint' action='https://acs-server-sandbox.3dsintegrator.com/v2/fingerprint' method='post'>
        <input name='threeDSMethodData' value='eyJtZXNzYWdlVHlwZSI6IkNSZXEiLCJtZXNzYWdlVmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMS4wIiwidGhyZWVEU1NlcnZlclRyYW5zSUQiOiIyYmUwMGViNS02NjJkLTRjOWUtYmM2Zi1kY2Y2ZjQwMWJjOTAiLCJhY3NUcmFuc0lEIjoiN2RjOTg2MGEtMzJkNy00ZGYxLTgyYjktZDhiMDhkNTdjNThjIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlV2luZG93U2l6ZSI6IjAxIn0' />
    </form>
</body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var sendFingerprint = document.getElementById('sendFingerprint')
    setTimeout(function() {
       document.sendFingerprint.submit();
    }, 100);
</script>
</html>">
```

Comment: Is there any error/warning in the console?

Comment: No it isn't throwing any error.